# Hierarchical query: from dual is ok, but from physical table is "ORA-01436"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-range

I get ranges using recursion with no problem in such way:

```
    WITH T1 AS (
     SELECT 1 ID, DATE '2010-08-10' STARTDATE, DATE '2010-08-12' UPTODATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 ID, DATE '2010-08-08' STARTDATE, DATE '2010-08-15' UPTODATE FROM DUAL
    )
    SELECT STARTDATE + LEVEL - 1 DT FROM T1
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= UPTODATE - STARTDATE
       AND PRIOR ID = ID
       AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL;
```

And from physical table

```
CREATE TABLE T2 (ID NUMBER(1), STARTDATE DATE, UPTODATE DATE);

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (1, DATE '2010-08-10', DATE '2010-08-12');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (2, DATE '2010-08-08', DATE '2010-08-15');

SELECT STARTDATE + LEVEL - 1 DT FROM T2
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= UPTODATE - STARTDATE
   AND PRIOR ID = ID
   AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL;
```

got a cycle error **ORA-01436**, but I see that these data and requests are absolutely identical.

What could be the problem, what to look for?

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the clause `NOCYCLE`?

Comment: @zaratustra yes, `NOCYCLE` produces both rows

Comment: I have just run it with no errors and the outputs are the same, are you sure you have one? I have Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production. If you keep experiencing this error probably this is an oracle bug. You have to contact with the oracle support

Comment: Really, yes, I got a problem. Just tried it on another database (9i) and also see no errors… I do not understand, maybe it's the environment variables or database settings affect?

Comment: You also can try this query on a virtual machine with a fresh oracle installation. [check this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) not to install oracle by yourself

Comment: This looks like bug 6451127; you'll need to look at My Oracle Support for details though (that bug, or doc ID 732871.1), and possibly raise a service request if you want to confirm that and get a patch for it.

Comment: What is `AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL` meant to do?  It looks like it will always return true.

Comment: @jonearles - it prevents it looping; the version in the bug report is using `dbms_random.string` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be bug 6451127, which is specific to the Oracle version you're using.

The example in the bug report uses a different non-deterministic function in the `prior` clause to [prevent cycling but still generate all the rows in the range](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535), but otherwise looks like the same issue to me.

You can get the details of that bug, a possible workaround, and information about a patch from My Oracle Support; start with document ID 732871.1 which links to the bug and patch. I can't reproduce any information from MOS here so this will unfortunately have to be vague.

You might need or want to raise a service request if you want to confirm that it is the same thing.